# supervisord stops silently but leaves processes running

Tags: unix, supervisord

I’m running some `gunicorn` processes using `supervisord`. When I run `sudo supervisord`, the processes start correctly, and a message like

```
2020-01-08 14:22:43,534 INFO success: my-great-process entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

is appended to `supervisord.log`. If I immediately run `supervisorctl` in another terminal instance, I can run relevant commands.

But after waiting for a while (anywhere from a minute to hours), `supervisorctl` returns

```
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
```

and a `grep` for the `supervisord` process returns no results. I can start `supervisord` again, but then all of my processes get duplicated and I need to kill the old ones manually.

When `supervisord` closes silently, nothing gets added to the log file.

What could be causing this, and how can I debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: in `supervisord.conf`, `nodaemon` was set to `true`. Removing this (the default is `false`) fixed the issue.